# How to parse complex object and array according to string

Tags: javascript, parsing

I have string in variable **y** which is like normal parsing equation used in js to parse object and I have complex object in variable **x** . Now I want to pass both variable in function named **parser** and function should return me parsed data from object . If you are not clear with my question please have a look at my example you will be crystal clear.

```
var a = {data:{info:{name:'mina'},interested: ['programming','makeup']}}
function parse(x, y) { var y = y.split('.').reverse();
    for (var j = x, i = (y.length - 1); i >= 0; --i) { 
        j =  j !== undefined && j[y[i]] !== undefined ?j[y[i]] : false;
    }
    if (j) {
        return j;
    }
}
parse(a,'data.info.name') //output = mina
parse(a,'data.info')  //{name: "mina"}
parse(a,'data.interested[1]')
```

This function works best for object parsing but I was unable to parse array using this function , I am looking for solution that can parse array as well . Please help me I tried my best I was able to parse simple array like **a.data.name[0]** but I was unable to parse complex array like **a.data.name[0][0].name[0]  (example)**

Please help Me to solve this problem

Comment: Your example is missing what `a` looks like.

Comment: @StefanBecker sorry I missed a ,  Just now I have updated please have a look.

Comment: So you are basically looking for [JavaScript eval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval), i.e. `eval('a.data.info.name')`?

Comment: no I am trying to parse from function  like my example **parser**

Comment: ... and you are trying to re-invent the wheel, because...?

Comment: I am trying to create my own framework , To learn how frameworks actually works.

Comment: Then you will need to write a lexer, i.e. a piece of code that reads the string and returns tokens, and a parser, i.e. a piece of code that translates the stream of tokens according to a grammar into a list of operations.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
let a = {
  users: {
      user1: {
          name: 'Mina',
          interested: ['programming', 'makeup', 'get an answer'],
          complexArray: [['test1'], ['test2',{
              ultimateTest: ['success', 'more success']
          }]]
      },
      user2: {
          name: 'Ernesto',
          interested: ['give an answer']
      }
  }
};

function getContent(element, address) {

    let i, j;
    let x, y, z;
    let length1, length2;
    let currentPosition = element;

    address = address.split('.');
    length1 = address.length;

    for (i = 0; i < length1; i++) {
        x = address[i].match(/\[\d\]/g);
        if (x !== null) {
            // ARRAY TYPE ADDRESS
            y = address[i].replace(/\[\d\]/g, '');
            currentPosition = currentPosition[y];
            length2 = x.length;
            for (j = 0; j < length2; j++) {
                z = x[j].replace(/\D/g, '');
                z = parseInt(z);
                currentPosition = currentPosition[z];
            }
        } else {
            // OBJECT TYPE ADDRESS
            currentPosition = currentPosition[address[i]];
        }
    }

    return (currentPosition);

}

getContent(a, 'users.user1.interested[0]'); // OUTPUT: 'programming'
getContent(a, 'users.user2.name'); // OUTPUT: 'Ernesto'
getContent(a, 'users.user1.complexArray[1][1].ultimateTest[0]'); // OUTPUT: 'success'
getContent(a, 'users.user1.complexArray[1][1].ultimateTest[1]'); // OUTPUT: 'more success'
```